# AWS Credentials Refreshed but Still Expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Anyone has any idea what the following error means?

```
#aws s3 ls

Credentials were refreshed, but the refreshed credentials are still expired.
```

I running it from the command line on the server, have already updated the keys couple of time but getting this error which i haven't seen before

Comment: Make sure that your awscli is up to date and that your system is time-synced.

Comment: If @jarmod suggestion doesn't resolve, check this bug report: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1283 (closed now, but may provide leads)

Comment: I had this happen to a system in an auto-scaling group in a dev environment. AWS CLI  version is *possible*, but I'm skeptical: I'd expect a bunch of systems to all break at the same time if something changed in AWS API. On top of that, my instance was launched only a month ago and installed the current CLI version at the time; and I have older instances in other groups with older CLIs that didn't break. My ASG only had 1 member (dev environment) so I don't know if it's an instance-specific issue or not; but terminating and re-launching a new one (with the same launch config) "fixed" it.

Answer (score 17):

I spoke with AWS support about this and they provided a resolution that does not involve changing TZs. What they advised was to check the IAM role assigned to your instanc.

Run this from the affected instance.

```
curl -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/IAM-ROLE
```

Check the expiration date of the

```
{
  "Code" : "",
  "LastUpdated" : "",
  "Type" : "",
  "AccessKeyId" : "",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "",
  "Token" : "",
  **"Expiration" : ""**

}
```

In my case, the expiration date showed a value from yesterday. These are temporary credentials that should refresh every so often but in this case, they refreshed but the expiration date did not change. This explains the error `AWS Credentials Refreshed but Still Expired`

**To resolve**

Simply unattach and re-attach the role associated with your instance to get new temporary credentials and try the S3 command again.

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: Thanks vr00n.  I had exactly the same problem.  Your advice of re-attaching the role worked perfectly for me, saved me hours of frustration trying to work out the problem.

Comment: @Graeme would do us and more folks good if you upvoted my answer :) Tx mate

Comment: @vr00n, I did upvote it. Somebody had previously downvotes it,I have no idea why, so my upvote brought it back to 0.

Comment: This error keeps happening after I un-attach and re-attach the IAM role. I have to un-attach and re-attach the IAM role every day to avoid the error. This is strange.

Comment: Can someone explain why this happens? I had the same problem!

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same issue.

My workflow is to assume a role via `aws sts assume-role`, then exporting the environment variables to actually use that token.
After this, I got:

`Credentials were refreshed, but the refreshed credentials are still expired.`

no matter what I've tried.
As it turned out I had a different issue, something set the following environment variable:

`AWS_CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION="2023-04-27T21:08:11+00:00"`

After I deleted that, I could finally use the assumed role.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when the role associated to the instance (in my case an ecs fargate) was accidentally deleted. Recreating the role solves the issue.

Comment: Had similar issue with ECS tasks. Solved by deleting policies and reattaching policies to the IAM role used in ECS task.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, It's solved now.

I have absolutely no idea what caused it, but I tried following

1. Re-generate new AWS keys
2. Recreate user
3. Change TZ to match the bucket region TZ
4. uninstall/reinstall the awscli

After doing all of the above I started getting

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.Tokyo.amazonaws.com/"
```

Which after searching got fixed by swaping in Tokyo with ap-northeast-1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your virtual machine, it could be an issue with your timezone. Change it to 'Set time automatically'.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, detaching and attaching the role works however, in my case, it wasn't  working from GUI. So I had to remove the IAM role association from the EC2 server using CLI.

This is what I did:

- Open AWS CLI or AWS-Shell that has permissions on EC2
- Then find the instance-profile-association ID for your instance id as follows:
  ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations --filters Name="instance-id",Values="**i-abcq34redfsl34534**"
- Use the **associationID** from the output above to disassociate IAM instance profile as follows:

ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id **iip-assoc-qwerty123456**

- Attach the IAM role again from GUI and voilà, it worked.

You can verify the association using the link below on your EC2 instance:

curl -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/IAM-ROLE

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just happen to me and I tried to detach and re-attach the role as specified above. I was unable to detach the role while the server was running, but after shutting down the server the process worked.

I detached the role from the GUI console using the EC2 Instances menu option :
Actions -> Security -> Modify IAM Role

After removing the role and then re-attaching it and starting the server back up, it all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I did clearing `AWS_CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION` environment variables and works for me.

```bash
unset AWS_CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION
```

```
Remove-Item Env:\AWS_CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed similar issue on ECS service (tasks) via following steps.

1. Open the role attached to the ECS service from `Network configuration > Service role`. (The role will open in new tab)
2. On the role tab, Visit `Revoke Sessions` tab and press button `Revoke Active Sessions`. Be aware of consequences of this action on your production.

**ECS > Services > Network configuration**
[image]

**ECS > Services > Network configuration > Service Role**
[image]

**Roles > Revoke Sessions**
[image]

If the above steps wont work, try detaching the policy from the role and adding it back again.

****Update**

The above solution was temporary. My issue got permanently fixed after following the instructions shared in [this answer](https://repost.aws/questions/QU-tAtxo2uQp-10bHXHccyTg/python-boto3-auto-refresh-credentials-when-assuming-role#ANY_EZbppkSjyZ66MMlCy2Qw)

I had to change my code from:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client("s3" region_name="eu-west-1")
```

To:

```
session = RefreshableBotoSession(region_name="eu-west-1").refreshable_session()
s3_client = session.client("s3")
```